# How to style "D-PAD" controller using only CSS to look like this?

Tags: html, css

[Example of finished DPAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgMhg.png)

```css
body {
    background-color: black; 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
div#controller {
    display: none; 
}
div#instructions {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white; 
    position: static;
    text-align: center; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div#instructions {
        display: none; 
    }
    div#controller { 
        display: flex; 
        position: relative;
        background-color: grey;
        opacity: 0.6;
        height: 33%;
        width: 80%;
    }
    div#controller.dpad {
        width: 60%; 
    }    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    div#instructions {
        display: none; 
    }
    div#controller {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        top: 300px;  
        background-color: grey; 
        opacity: 0.6; 
        height: 50%;
        width: 80%;
    }
    div#controller.dpad {
        width: 33%;
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
        
        <!-- The CSS is missing! Your mission is to re-create it -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="env3d.css" />
        
        <script src="http://css.operatoroverload.com/exercise/bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="http://css.operatoroverload.com/exercise/game.js"></script>        
        
        <script type="text/javascript">         

         function playGame() {
             console.log("playGame");
             var game = new Game();

             game.setup();
             
             var env;
             if (game.env) {
                 env = game.env;
             } else {
                 env = new env3d.Env();
             }
            
             env.loop = game.loop.bind(game);             
             env.start();
         }
         
         window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            playGame();
         });
         
         document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
         });         
         
        </script>
         
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="controller">
            <div class="dpad">
                <button env3d-key="KEY_UP">UP</button>
                <button env3d-key="KEY_LEFT">LEFT</button>
                <button env3d-key="KEY_RIGHT">RIGHT</button>
                <button env3d-key="KEY_DOWN">DOWN</button>
            </div>
            <button env3d-key="KEY_A">A</button>
            <button env3d-key="KEY_Z">Z</button>            
        </div>
        <div id="instructions">Use arrow keys to change camera angle, A to zoom in, Z to zoom out.</div>
        <div id="env3d"></div>        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

I have this small little project to complete. However, I'm completely stuck on how to code the mobile controllers using only CSS. I cannot style it to look like the picture.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction of where to go?

Thanks! Your help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, we're in the same web development class.

Which part do you need help with?

First, you have to resize and position the `#controller` and `.dpad` divs at the bottom of the screen. You need to use the `position`, `width`, and `height` properties for this.

Then you have to position the buttons inside their container divs (also by using `position`, `width`, and `height`). You can select each button individually using the `element>element`, `attribute=value`, and/or `:nth-child()` selectors described [here.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

In case you need it, [this](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) page explains how to vertically center an element by giving it the properties `position: relative (or absolute);`, `top: 50%;`, and `transform: translateY(-50%);`. (Centering horizontally would be `position: relative (or absolute);`, `left: 50%;`, and `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Hope this helps you!